# How do I use jquery to validate form fields, that was populated dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a list of 10 questions, used in rating a user, something like this: [image]

The list is gotten dynamically, based on the users Occupation. This is how I am getting the list:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.AppraisalQuestions.ToList().Count; i++)
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.AppraisalQuestions[i].QuestionId)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.AppraisalQuestions[i].QuestionDescription)
    <p>
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.AppraisalQuestions[i].QuestionDescription)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.AppraisalQuestions[i].SelectedAnswer, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </p>
    <div class="row lead evaluation">
        <div id="colorstar" class="starrr ratable"></div>
        <span id="count">0</span> star(s) - <span id="meaning"> </span>
        @foreach (var answer in Model.AppraisalQuestions[i].PossibleAnswers)
        {
            //var inputId = Model.AppraisalQuestions[i].QuestionId + "-" + answer.ID;
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.AppraisalQuestions[i].SelectedAnswer, new { id = "SelectedAns", required = "required" })
        }
    </div> 
}
```

This is the model:

```
public class AppraisalInputModel
{
    public int AppraisalId { get; set; }

    public AppraisalInputModel()
    {
        AppraisalQuestions = new List<AppraisalQuestionInputModel>();
    }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string JobTitle { get; set; }
    public int StaffId { get; set; }
    public int ScorerId { get; set; }
    public int BranchId { get; set; }
    public string AppraisalTitle { get; set; }

    public IList<AppraisalQuestionInputModel> AppraisalQuestions { get; set; }
}
```

and this is the AppraisalQuestionInputModel

```
 public class AppraisalQuestionInputModel
{
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public string QuestionDescription { get; set; }
    public bool IsGeneral { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Score")]
    public int? SelectedAnswer { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<AnswerVM> PossibleAnswers => new List<AnswerVM>()
    {
        new AnswerVM {ID = 1, Text = "1 - Poor"},
        new AnswerVM {ID = 2, Text = "2 - Below Expectation"},
        new AnswerVM {ID = 3, Text = "3 - Meets Expectation"},
        new AnswerVM {ID = 4, Text = "4 - Good"},
        new AnswerVM {ID = 5, Text = "5 - Excellent"},
    };
}
```

This is the script section code:

```
 @section Scripts{
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script type="text/javascript">
// Starrr plugin (https://github.com/dobtco/starrr)
        var __slice = [].slice;

        (function($, window) {
            var Starrr;

            Starrr = (function() {
                Starrr.prototype.defaults = {
                    rating: void 0,
                    numStars: 5,
                    change: function(e, value) {}
                };

                function Starrr($el, options) {
                    var i,
                        _,
                        _ref,
                        _this = this;

                    this.options = $.extend({}, this.defaults, options);
                    this.$el = $el;
                    _ref = this.defaults;
                    for (i in _ref) {
                        _ = _ref[i];
                        if (this.$el.data(i) != null) {
                            this.options[i] = this.$el.data(i);
                        }
                    }
                    this.createStars();
                    this.syncRating();
                    this.$el.on('mouseover.starrr', 'span', function(e) {
                        return _this.syncRating(_this.$el.find('span').index(e.currentTarget) + 1);
                    });
                    this.$el.on('mouseout.starrr', function() {
                        return _this.syncRating();
                    });
                    this.$el.on('click.starrr', 'span', function(e) {
                        return _this.setRating(_this.$el.find('span').index(e.currentTarget) + 1);
                    });
                    this.$el.on('starrr:change', this.options.change);
                }

                Starrr.prototype.createStars = function() {
                    var _i, _ref, _results;

                    _results = [];
                    for (_i = 1, _ref = this.options.numStars; 1 <= _ref ? _i <= _ref : _i >= _ref; 1 <= _ref ? _i++ : _i--) {
                        _results.push(this.$el.append("<span class='glyphicon .glyphicon-star-empty'></span>"));
                    }
                    return _results;
                };

                Starrr.prototype.setRating = function(rating) {
                    if (this.options.rating === rating) {
                        rating = void 0;
                    }
                    this.options.rating = rating;
                    this.syncRating();
                    return this.$el.trigger('starrr:change', rating);
                };

                Starrr.prototype.syncRating = function(rating) {
                    var i, _i, _j, _ref;

                    rating || (rating = this.options.rating);
                    if (rating) {
                        for (i = _i = 0, _ref = rating - 1; 0 <= _ref ? _i <= _ref : _i >= _ref; i = 0 <= _ref ? ++_i : --_i) {
                            this.$el.find('span').eq(i).removeClass('glyphicon-star-empty').addClass('glyphicon-star');
                        }
                    }
                    if (rating && rating < 5) {
                        for (i = _j = rating; rating <= 4 ? _j <= 4 : _j >= 4; i = rating <= 4 ? ++_j : --_j) {
                            this.$el.find('span').eq(i).removeClass('glyphicon-star').addClass('glyphicon-star-empty');
                        }
                    }
                    if (!rating) {
                        return this.$el.find('span').removeClass('glyphicon-star').addClass('glyphicon-star-empty');
                    }
                };

                return Starrr;

            })();
            return $.fn.extend({
                starrr: function() {
                    var args, option;

                    option = arguments[0], args = 2 <= arguments.length ? __slice.call(arguments, 1) : [];
                    return this.each(function() {
                        var data;

                        data = $(this).data('star-rating');
                        if (!data) {
                            $(this).data('star-rating', (data = new Starrr($(this), option)));
                        }
                        if (typeof option === 'string') {
                            return data[option].apply(data, args);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        })(window.jQuery, window);

        $(function() {
            return $(".starrr").starrr();
        });

        $(document).ready(function () {
            var starCount;

            var correspondence = ["", "Poor", "Below Expectation", "Above Expectation", "Good", "Excelent"];

            $('.ratable').on('starrr:change', function(e, value) {

                $(this).closest('.evaluation').children('#count').html(value);
                $(this).closest('.evaluation').children('#SelectedAns').val(value);

                starCount = $(this).closest('.evaluation').children('#SelectedAns').val(value);

                if (starCount === null) {
                    swal("", "Please Enter First Name", "error");
                }
                $(this).closest('.evaluation').children('#meaning').html(correspondence[value]);

                var currentval = $(this).closest('.evaluation').children('#count').html();


                var target = $(this).closest('.evaluation').children('.indicators');
                target.css("color", "black");
                target.children('.rateval').val(currentval);
                target.children('#textwr').html(' ');





            });

            $('#hearts-existing').on('starrr:change', function(e, value) {
                $('#count-existing').html(value);
            });
        });



</script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
        });


    </script>

}
```

And all questions must be answered. How Do I validate to make sure that all questions are answered?

I have tried `form.Validate()` but it is not working.

Comment: Its not clear what you are asking. What is your model? What validation attributes are applied to its properties. And what is editable (all you have shown are hidden inputs) And a `@foreach` loop that does not make sense and is generating invalid html

Comment: Ok, I will update and add the model.

Comment: There is a lot that is not making sense. You `foreach` loop is generating multiple hidden inputs for `SelectedAnswer` which is generating invalid html, and only the first input will be bound in any case. You `required = "required"` is pointless on a hidden input and in any case, that is HTML-5 validation (and is disabled by default assuming you are using mvc validation using `jquery.validate`. You do have a `ValidationMessageFor()` for `SelectedAnswer`, but assuming you are using `jquery.validate`, then hidden inputs are not validated by default (although you can configure that)

Comment: I assume you are using a jquery plugin for the 'stars', in which case you need to assign the value (1 - 5) to a single hidden input for `SelectedAnswer`, but you would need to show you plugin and scripts for us to understand what you are doing

Comment: Ok....I will edit again...sorry for the lag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your view is generating 5 hidden inputs for the same `SelectedAnswer`. You need only one (only the value of the first one will be bound by the `DefaultModelBinder`), and you need to set its value in the `starrr:change` event.

However, hidden inputs are not validated by default so you also need to configure the `$.validator` to give you client side validation.

First, modify your view to delete the `foreach` loop and replace it with a single hidden input. Note also the `id` attributes have been replaced with class names (duplicate `id` attributes is invalid html)

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.AppraisalQuestions.ToList().Count; i++)
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.AppraisalQuestions[i].QuestionId)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.AppraisalQuestions[i].QuestionDescription)
    <p>
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.AppraisalQuestions[i].QuestionDescription)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.AppraisalQuestions[i].SelectedAnswer, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </p>
    <div class="row lead evaluation">
        <div class="starrr ratable"></div> // remove invalid id attribute
        <span class="count">0</span> star(s) - <span class="meaning"> </span> 
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.AppraisalQuestions[i].SelectedAnswer, new { @class = "rating" }) 
    </div> 
}
```

Then to set the value of the input so it is posted back when you submit the form

```
$('.ratable').on('starrr:change', function(e, value) {
    var container = $(this).closest('.evaluation'); // cache it
    container.children('.count').html(value); // modify
    container.children('.rating').val(value); // set value of input
    container.children('.meaning').html(correspondence[value]); // modify
    ....
})
```

Note the code relating to `starCount` does not seem necessary, and its not clear what some of the other code in that method is doing or why you have it (for example `currentval` is just the same value as `value`)

Finally, to get client side validation, add the following script (but **not** inside `document.ready()`)

```
$.validator.setDefaults({ 
    ignore: ":hidden:not('.rating')"
});
```

Comment: Wow!...Worked like a charm!....Wish I could mark as the answer more than once!!!.....Thanks!.